# Graceful shutdown of asynchronous processes running in java on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ecs, sigterm, graceful-shutdown

When sending SIGTERM to tomcat on Amazon ECS, is it possible to kill the process (so called graceful shutdown) waiting for the asynchronous process to terminate?
By setting unloadDelay in tomcat configuration (server.xml), it is possible to suspend the process termination until the synchronous process terminates after SIGTERM is sent with `kill -15`, but it is not possible to do so for asynchronous processes.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about the asynchronous processes?  Are these Java threads in the background or external processes?

Comment: @stdunbar The former, where a thread pool is created on the Java program and asynchronous processing is performed there.

Comment: Your asynchronous processes should register listeners for when the container is being shut-down, so they can terminate themselves.